# sobjects and related fields

Tags: apex, sobject

How to get the account.name from the sobject?

I have tried getting the account itself but that doesn't work and debugging the map doesnt show the account name either.

```
    list<opportunity> opplst = new list<opportunity>();
    opplst = [select id, accountid, account.name from opportunity where accountid != null limit 1];
    
    map<id,sobject> gg = new map<id,sobject>();
    
    gg.put(opplst[0].id, opplst[0]);
    
    system.debug(gg);
    
    system.debug((string)gg.get(opplst[0].id).get('account.name'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the Dynamic Apex methods are "smart" enough to traverse relationships for you, so you have to do it yourself.

Fortunately, you can do this with getSObject and get:

```
String accountName = gg.get(opplst[0].Id).getSObject('Account').get('Name');
```

It would be ideal to avoid this when necessary, but if you need code like this, that's how you get it done.

Also, it should be noted that while:

```
someOpportunity.Account.Name
```

Is *null-safe* while traversing a field path (e.g. won't throw an exception if Account is null), the getSobject method is not null-safe. I know you filtered this out in your example query, but if you aren't sure a value would be null, you'd want to use the Safe Navigation Operator (`?.`):

```
String accountName = gg.get(opplst[0].Id)?.getSObject('Account')?.get('Name');
```